# Cannot Access Class Field When Inheriting

Tags: c#, class, inheritance

I'm developing a game, and I'm having trouble accessing a field for a class for my questing system. In this system, Quests can have multiple goals, and goals can be of different types. So in this example I have a fetch quest called "Ultimate Fetch", there are two fetch goals, and each fetch goal is associated with an item id. I'm having difficulty accessing the item id.

The quest class looks like this:

```
public class Quest
{
    public List<Goal> goals { get; set; } = new List<Goal>();
    public string QuestName { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int XpReward { get; set; }
    public bool completed { get; set; }
}
```

The goal class looks like this:

```
public class Goal
{
    public Quest Quest { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public bool completed { get; set; }
    public int currentAmount { get; set; }
    public int requiredAmount { get; set; }

}
```

The FetchGoal class looks like this:

```
public class FetchGoal : Goal
{
    public int itemId { get; set; } //<-- I'm having issues accessing this

    public FetchGoal(Quest quest, int _itemId, string _description, bool _completed, int _currentAmount, int _requiredAmount)
    {
        this.Quest = quest;
        this.itemId = _itemId;
        this.completed = _completed;
        this.description = _description;
        this.currentAmount = _currentAmount;
        this.requiredAmount = _requiredAmount;
    }

}
```

And the Fetch Quest class looks like this:

```
public class UltimateFetchQuest : Quest
{
    public UltimateFetchQuest()
    {
        QuestName = "Ultimate Fetch";
        description = "Fetch Stuff!!";
        XpReward = 100;
        goals.Add(new FetchGoal(this, 0, "Fetch 5 things", false, 0, 2));
        goals.Add(new FetchGoal(this, 1, "Fetch 2 widgets", false, 0, 2));
    }
}
```

For simplicity sake I just have a button to try and access the field, like this:

```
    UltimateFetchQuest FetchQuest = new UltimateFetchQuest();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Goal> lstGoals = FetchQuest.goals;
        int intItemId = lstGoals[0].itemId; // <-- This does not work
    }
```

The 2nd line in the button click event is not valid. I'm thinking this is because I'm accessing the goals  list, and not the fetchgoals. The part that confuses me is when I debug the program, I can see the field using intellisense:

[image]

There seems to be a path to access it, but as you can see here, I cannot:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hint: what do you expect to happen if `lstGoals` contains something that *isn't* a `FetchQuest`? You've said "This is a list of goals - any kind of goal is fine." `FetchQuest` is only *one* kind of goal - others may not have an `itemId` property.

Comment: Hmmm, that is a good point. I suppose that makes sense.

Comment: When you are debugging, the `Goal` is displayed as its most specific type: `FetchGoal`. In `button1_Click`, you are accessing each  item as `Goal`, which is why you cannot access `itemId`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern matching

```cs
if(lstGoals[0] is Fetchgoal fetchgoal)
{
    var id = fetchgoal.itemId;
}
```

Better is to use a switch though since you have multiple goals as you said

```cs
switch(lstGoals[0])
{
    case Fetchgoal fetchgoal:
     // stuff
     break;

    case OtherGoal othergoal:
     // stuff
    break;
}
```

Comment: Side note: we call `lstGoals[0] is Fetchgoal fetchgoal` and alike constructions _pattern matching_

Comment: As far as I can tell the switch statement is perfect for what I'm doing. Hopefully it stays that way haha. Thank you.